# The equation $ 4 \sin^2 (x)+10x^2=\cos x \ $ has

Tags: real-analysis

Which is correct option ?

> The equation $ 4 \sin^2 (x)+10x^2=\cos x \ $ has
>
> (i) no real roots
>
> (ii) two real roots

**What I've tried:**

Let $ f(x)= \sin^2 (x)+10x^2-\cos x \ $

If possible let $ f \ $ has two real root $ p,q \ $ say

Then $f'(x) \ $ vanishes between $ p, q \ $

But $ f'(x)=20x+4 \sin 2x+\sin x  \neq 0 \ $

So no real root.

Am I correct?

Comment: No, $f'(x)=0$ implies turning points not roots...

Comment: Doesn't $f'(0) = 0$ ?  @KarnWatcharasupat He means there is a "turning point" in between the roots since the function is not identically zero.

Comment: Well, caveat emptor, but it looks like it's got roots at about -0.25 and 0.25 according to gnuplot!

Comment: @yourmath Your solution is wrong, since $f'(0) = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $f(0) = -1 < 0, f(1) \ge 8 > 0$. Thus IVT says $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (0,1)$. This shows it has at least a real root, and you have only $2$ choices to choose from and it has to be the second one.

Comment: Also can point out that it is an even function so it has an even number of roots.